A 300 page document, does not compile when adding \usepackage{hyperref}: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]
I downloaded the LaTeX source found in
https://arxiv.org/abs/2407.13649
(a 300 page manuscript)
but added
\usepackage{hyperref}:
when compiling with pdflatex or xelatex I receive
./global-existence-irrotational.tex:5337: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again> 
                   \expandafter 
l.5337 I
        n this subsection, we give the comparison estimates of the connectio.

the packages loaded are the following
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

Is any incompatibility with the packages, or is the order important, or is there any trick to compile this document nevertheless?
thanks
Uwe Brauer

well  start to debug it. Put everything in a test folder, put \end{document} in various places and remove content until you know what in the body is triggering the error, then start to remove packages until you have a complete, minimal example that you can show here.

well you are lucky that it doesn't errors more in view of all the \def in the preamble. Change the subsection in line 5334 to \subsection{Derivative control on $\tr\chi$, \texorpdfstring{$\chih$}{hatchi} and $\zeta$}

Off-topic: subfigure is deprecated for decades. See the link for more information. Loading graphicx after tikz has been loaded is useless. amssymb also loads amsfonts . … So I would suggest to tidy the preamble first.

ok, thanks for the answers, (I did not write that document) I just want desperately to compile with hyperref otherwise reading is very very difficult.
I try make the changes suggested

Thank you Ulrike very much, your suggestion \subsection{Derivative control on $\tr\chi$, \texorpdfstring{$\chih$}{hatchi} and $\zeta$}  solved the issue!

Ok, thank you ... but I doubt future readers with a similar problem will have a clue what happened or why your change works ...

@UweBrauer Thanks for the pointer: I'll use it for examples of how to misuse LaTeX.

Hi, thanks to all of you, from my own experience I can tell you that most mathematicians I know, have very limited Latex knowledge, tend to use PlainTeX constructions and incredible amount of macros (instead of using features of an advanced editor). If I were the collaborator I would try to correct these constructions or to debug the document, but in this case I urgently needed to compile the document with hyperref, otherwise 300 pages are difficult to read

Your document used in a heading a command that exploded when hyperref tried to make bookmarks.
\subsection{Derivative control on $\tr\chi$, $\chih$ and $\zeta$}

where \chih was defined as \newcommand{\chih}{\hat{\chi}}.
This was quite easy to find: the error message mentioned the line of the error and a bit commenting out in the region around the error line directly identified the problem.
As always with hyperref the easiest fix is to provide an alternative text for the bookmarks:
\subsection{Derivative control on $\tr\chi$, \texorpdfstring{$\chih$}{chi} and $\zeta$}


Too long for a comment:
Without even using hyperref, the first that I see is that \b is defined  (wrong, it is already defined) twice (wrong, useful only to increase entropy) using \def (wrong, when the author does not know the risks).
The command \b is a standard command that needs an argument (a character to underline, e.g. \b{a} or \b a or even \b{} but not {\b}).
Luckily, there is not need of underline characters in this way in the original document, so \def\b{\beta} can be used without problems but without hyperref.
When  hyperref is loaded after this definition restores the original behaviour of \b, so that it will produce an error  (Argument of \OT1\b has an extra }.) with some like $a^{\b}$ or in the best case the default unexpected output (e.g.,$\b a$ will not produce "βa" but "a̲").
If you load hyperref before, your custom definitions prevail, but this can break this package or any other loaded before and using the same macro names in unexcepted ways.
Conclusion: change all these \def by \newcommand. Already defined and duplicated definitions will turn on the alerts allowing you to debug the preamble in this aspect.
